# Viewing a PDF file in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to view a PDF file within the body of my cakephp application after uploading it, more like an iframe. The upload works fine but the challenge that i have now is opening the pdf file.

Here is my upload function in my controller which is working fine

```
function uploadFile() {
$file = $this->data['QmsProcedureKnowledgeManagement']['file'];
if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
$id = String::uuid();
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], APP . 'qms_procedure_km/' . $file['name'])) {
$this->request->data['QmsProcedureKnowledgeManagement']['filename'] = $file['name'];
$this->request->data['QmsProcedureKnowledgeManagement']['filesize'] = $file['size'];
$this->request->data['QmsProcedureKnowledgeManagement']['filemime'] = $file['type'];
return true;
}
}
return false;
}
```

and here is how i am trying to view the pdf in view.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(APP.'qms_procedure_km/'. $qmsProcedureKnowledgeManagement['QmsProcedureKnowledgeManagement']['filename']); ?>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any files you have inside of `APP . 'qms_procedure_km/'` cannot be directly accessed from a web browser. This is by design.

If you want the PDF to be accessible to *anybody* with the URL, you just need to store the file in a location that *can* be directly accessed from a web browser (e.g. `WWW_ROOT . 'qms_procedure_km/'`).

If you want the PDF to be accessible only for certain people (e.g. users who are logged in), you should continue storing the file in a location that *cannot* be directly accessed from a web browser, but you'll need to write a controller action that will determine that the user is allowed to view the PDF and then display it to them using [`CakeResponse::file()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file) (CakePHP >= 2.3.0) or [Media Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html) (CakePHP < 2.3.0).